# Can the output of one command be piped to two other commands?

Tags: unix, bash

How can I pipe the output of one command to the input of two other commands simultaneously?

Comment: Yes. See this stackoverflow question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/670784/redirecting-bash-stdout-stderr-to-two-places

Answer (score 75, accepted):

It sounds like the `tee` command will do what you want.

The key is to use

```
>( )
```

for [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html).  With `tee`, use the following pattern:

```
tee >(proc1) >(proc2) >(proc3) | proc4
```

So if you wanted to use the output of `ls` as input to two different `grep` programs, save the output of each `grep` to different files, and pipe all of the results through `less`, try:

```
ls -A | tee >(grep ^[.] > hidden-files) >(grep -v ^[.] > normal-files) | less
```

The results of the `ls -A` will be "piped" into both `grep`s.  The file `hidden-files` will have the contents from the output of the first `grep`, and `normal-files` will have the results of the second `grep`.  <del>All of the files will be shown in the pager `less`.</del> **EDIT**: what you see in `less` is the **same exact output** of `ls -A`, not the result of the `grep`s. If you want to modify the output from `ls -A` to `less`, (e.g. swapping the order so normal files are listed before hidden ones) then try this:

```
ls -A | tee >(grep ^[.]) >(grep -v ^[.]) >/dev/null | less
```

Without `>/dev/null`, the output of `grep`s would be appended to the output of `ls -A` instead of replacing it.

[source](http://linux.byexamples.com/archives/144/redirect-output-to-multiple-processes/)

Comment: this one is very good !

Comment: +1 because even after 10 years of shell scripting, I'd never seen this!

Answer (score 7):

Use "tee".

Example:

```
grep someSearchString someFile | tee /dev/tty | wc -l > grepresult
```

This will send the output of the grep command to both the terminal and to [wc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wc_%28Unix%29) (whose output is in turn redirected to the file grepresult).

"Tee" is explained in the Wikipedia article *[tee (command)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_(command))*. Central is: "The tee command reads standard input, then writes its content to standard output and simultaneously copies it into the specified file(s) or variables.".